# Class vs Interface as type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-typings

I came across this recently where I am not sure whether to use the interface or class to define a particular type.

> Note: This question is *NOT* asking about the difference between a `class` and `interface`

For example, given this class and interface

```
interface IMyClass {
  foo: string;
  bar: () => string;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
  foo = 'foo';
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

I would use either the class or interface as the type in a function argument.

#### Option A - Use *class* as type

```
function identityByClass(value: MyClass): MyClass {
  return value;
}
```

#### Option B - Use *interface* as type

```
function identityByInterface(value: IMyClass): IMyClass {
  return value;
}
```

From my point of view, I think either is fine but I prefer to use the class to avoid syncing all methods/properties on the interface. I see the interface as only a template/contract that a class must abide by.

However, most times, in my case, the class often adds more methods/properties that are not on the interface definition.

Case in point, this class below.

```
class MyClassPlus implements IMyClass {
  foo = 'foo';
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
  doMore() {
    console.log('more stuff here!');
  }
}
```

In which case I could no longer use the two interchangeably.

Any links to best practices would be nice too. Thanks.

Comment: Generally if use interface , You don't care `MyClassPlus` have more function right? , Becase system is depency interface  not `MyClassPlus`. if yes you care about that , it problem maybe is how to "desigen" a more gerenic interface for your system.

Comment: Hey @TimChang! Right That's the question. Once I have added to the class on top of what is defined on the interface, I must use the class if I want access to those added methods or properties. The question is whether to sync the interface or just use the class as the type for the augmented class.

Comment: Possible you have diffrence behavior at same time? if that's your case , you can define two interface to handle that like `void DoSome<T>(T myclass) where T : IMyClassA , IMyClassB ` because you split interface , so you can don't sync all MyClassPlus methods/properties to one interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure whether to use the interface or class to define a particular type.

Both classes and interfaces create a type, so in principle they can be used interchangeably. As you pointed out, an interface is like a public contract, whereas a class implements this contract.

But consider following cases:

1. What, if you need to change `MyClass`?
2. `MyClass` exposes more implementation details by revealing, it is a class type.

A refactored, new type signature of `MyClass` may not be valid to be used as function parameter in function `identityByClass` anymore. So you would need to refactor all consumers - duh... With a [separate type interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), that is more unlikely to happen.

Example for point 2: a client could come up with the idea of getting static properties of `MyClass` (interfaces don't make it obvious by rather hiding implementation details):

```
class MyClass {
  static baz(){}
  foo = 'foo';
}

function identityByClass(value: MyClass) {
  console.log((value.constructor as any).baz) // function baz()
  // there we go. do something with static baz() method of MyClass
}
```

By the way: It is not only about interfaces and class types. [Type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) offer powerful features like mapped or conditional types, union etc. and can be used in favor of interfaces most times.

> However, most times, in my case, the class often adds more methods/properties that are not on the interface definition.

You do not need to sync class and interface types. In order to keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), two options come to my mind:

1. [Interfaces can extend class type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes), to get rid of redundant declarations.
2. Pick only those class properties, that are required to the consumer.

**I would favor the second point over all other alternatives**, as it follows design principles like [Information Hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) or [Loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). Example:

```
class MyClass {
  foo = 'foo';
  tooMuchDetail = "hide me"
}

// just pick, what we need (foo here)
type OnlyNeededProps = Pick<MyClass, "foo">

function doSomethingWithFoo(a: OnlyNeededProps) {
  a.foo
  a.tooMuchDetail // error, unknown (OK)
}

doSomethingWithFoo(new MyClass())
```

Comment: thanks for all that information, and all the links! Especially about the interface-segregation principle. Interesting point about the `static` properties too.

Answer (score 2):

One benefit you gain by using an interface to define types is that the interface itself is eliminated after compilation.  This reduces the overall bloat of your application, which is a strong argument for using an interface in this situation.

You might find this useful: https://jameshenry.blog/typescript-classes-vs-interfaces/

Comment: But in this question, the choice is between having a class, vs. having a class *and* an interface.